# NOT NULL constraint failed but field is not null

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am trying to add a new item using my web form.

But I get this error. The email is not null though which I verified from a print statement.

at this line

```
File "/Users/j/udacity/item_catalog/item-catalog-190/application.py", line 131, in newItem
    session.commit()


IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: category.email [SQL: u'INSERT INTO category (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'Pilates', None)]


@app.route('/catalog/new', methods=['GET','POST'])
def newItem():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        placeholder=request.form['category']
        category = Category(name=placeholder)
        print "**********", login_session['email']
        email = login_session['email']
        newThing = Item(name=request.form['name'], description=request.form['description'], price=request.form['price'],category=category, email=email)
        session.add(newThing)
        session.commit()
        return redirect('/catalog')
    else:
        return render_template('newitem.html')
```

These are my two tables.

```
class Item(Base):
__tablename__ = 'item'

name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
description = Column(String(250))
price = Column(String(8))
category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
email = Column(String(250),nullable=False)
category = relationship(Category)


class Category(Base):
__tablename__ = 'category'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
email = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `category` table requires the `email` field to be `NOT NULL`, and when you create a new category:

```
category = Category(name=placeholder)
```

The default value of the `email` field is `NULL`.

This is the query for the `INSERT`:

```
SQL: u'INSERT INTO category (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'Pilates', None)
```

As you can see, the second paramenter (which is the `email`) is None (which translates to `null` in SQL.

You might wanna change your code to:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    placeholder=request.form['category']
    email = login_session['email'] # moved the email here
    print "**********", login_session['email']
    category = Category(name=placeholder, email=email) # here you have the email variable so you can use it
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized also my error is that I am not trying to create a new category. Rather I want the user to select from existing categories so I have to make those changes as well. Thanks for explaining it to me.Also I realized it was because I added the email field afterward and forgot to add the email field in that spot.

Comment: I upvoted it. But I can't accept the answer yet. I have to wait another six minutes. Thanks for answering so fast.

Comment: Sure :) no problem.